# Conflict between p:ajax and f:validate

Tags: jsf, primefaces

With this code the listener is not running but if I remove the tag `f:validate` the listener is called correctly. Does anyone know a solution to avoid having to do the validation within the managed bean?

```
<p:inputText id="txtTalla" label="Talla (cm)" value="#{mbVPretratamiento.pretratamiento.talla}" >
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{mbVPretratamiento.calcularIMC()}" update="txtIMC"/>
    <f:validateLongRange minimum="100" maximum="220"/>
</p:inputText>
```

Comment: I do assume you checked if the validation fails, right? Added a p:messages? Update that? And does it work with an `h:inputText` and `f:ajax`?

Comment: You have reason, when fails validation does not run the listener..

Comment: So it is solved now?